# Disable WiFi transmitter keeping receiver enable

Tags: wifi

I'm brand new here, I hope my question will be clear enough.

I would like to know if it is possible to disable the Wifi transmitter on the WiFi device, but keeping the receiver enable?

The purpose is to stricly forbid any WiFi emsission before to get an "authorization" througt WiFi reception, which will allow transmission.
Then, still througt WiFi, I'll need to disable the transmitter  till the next transmission "authorization"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How would you get authorized without transmitting anything? Unless the server already knows you, something like a static list... but then you wouldn't need to be authorized. Are you talking about something like turning off wifi to save power, and only turn it on again when called? A timer would work. But there shouldn't be much wifi "traffic" anyway if you're not doing anything, just sitting quietly but still connected, or did you find there is?

Comment: If it isn't to save power (i.e., it's for stealth or something), just configure a firewall to not allow anything out of the wifi adapter.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. The authentication and authorization process on a WiFi link is two-way communication.

Comment: Actually it is possible. It requires WiFi card with RFMON mode enabled and software like aircrack to sniff for packets without having to associate with an access point. If we find any specific packet on the network, we'll enable regular WiFi connection. But that's just the theory, I didn't try that before.

Comment: Thank you mark, I'll dig in that way. What's more I'll define the whole protocol for both "master" and "slave" WiFi units, so I'm completely free. Is the stock WiFi module of the Raspberry allow RFMON?

Comment: It's possible assuming that aircrack cracks.  Pretty sure it won't send any packets unless it is trying to authenticate -- but you could easily explore this with a packet sniffer, which if nothing else will show you whatever packets are coming from your own NIC.